# Fancybox load div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

The title says it all. I want to load everything inside the link WHEN clicked on not while the page is loading. The way I noticed it was loading along with the page was my adblock was detecting ads and i was testing it in a blank page. I'm planning on using many links like this on the same page and it would take forever to load if it was done this way.

question: Is there a way to load the div inside the link when clicked on instead of loading along the page?

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpL14ysg/

the code:

```
<a href="#divForm" id="btnForm">Load Form</a>

<div id="divForm" style="display:none">
  <iframe style='overflow: hidden; border: 0; width: 600px; height: 480px' src='http://embed.novamov.com/embed.php?v=19bf3a4b7fe49' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#btnForm").fancybox({
        'onStart': function() { $("#divForm").css("display","block"); },            
        'onClosed': function() { $("#divForm").css("display","none"); }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the normal fancybox way to load an iframe. With a look at the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) you can tell fancybox to create the iframe on click.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href='video url here' id="btnForm">Load Form</a>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnForm").fancybox({
        width: 600,
        height: 480
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qpL14ysg/1/